# How to prevent clicking UITableView second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My app calls a block in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath and in the block it presents a view controller. If I click the cell second time when the first click is in progress, it crashes.
How can I prevent the cell to be clicked second time?

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


    [dataController fetchAlbum:item
         success:^(Album *album) {
            ...
            ...

            [self presentViewController:photoViewController animated:YES completion:nil];


               }];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the beginning of `didSelectRow`, turn off user interaction on your table.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    ...
```

You may want to turn it back on later in the completion of `fetchAlbum` (Do this on the main thread) so that if the user comes back to this view (or the fetch fails), they can interact with the table again.

Answer (score 7):

For swift 3 :

When user select a row, turn off user interactions :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Don't forget to turn it on back whenever the view appear :

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either prevent multiple clicks (by disabling the table or covering it up with a spinner) or you could make `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` present your view controller *synchronously*   and load your "album" after it's been presented. I'm a fan of the latter as it makes the UI feel more responsive.

Comment: Personally, if the load takes more than about 0.5s (roughly the time it takes to present the new view animated), I find that approach _less_ responsive as it leaves me staring at a blank screen while loading instead of a populated view controller with an activity indicator. However, if the load is quick, I would definitely recommend the synchronous page load you suggest so that the data can load while the animation is in progress.

Comment: I wouldn't expect you to be staring at a blank screen. I would show you a blank page with the most beautiful loading spinner you had ever laid eyes on. :)

Comment: Agreed. The data takes the same amount of time to load either way, but with this approach the app reacts to the touch immediately. With the OPs approach I am left wondering if my cell tap is going to be actioned

Answer (score 1):

For a cleaner approach:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    defer {
      tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

This way you're much less prone to errors due to forgetfulness.

Answer (score 0):

You want to disable user interaction on the *cell*:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

As Stonz2 points out, you probably want to do it to the entire tableview though, rather than the specific cell if you're presenting a VC.

Comment: While the OP did ask about disabling their cell specifically, I would think they probably don't want to present multiple modal photo viewer controllers at the same time.

Comment: More than likely, but I answered the question nonetheless ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell?.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

then 
set back to true before you navigate to another view, otherwise when you return back to your table the cell will be still disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar approach like [Skaal answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43779921/14206959)  but in a different way. This solution will work for any swift version .

Create a property named isPresentingVC in your view controller and set it to true.

```
var isPresentingVC: Bool = true
```

Inside didSelect row, try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if isPresentingVC {
       isPresentingVC = false
       //do your work like go to another view controller
    }
 }
```

Now in viewWillAppear or viewDidDisappear reset its value to true

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    isPresentingVC = true
}
```